# Is it possible to forward a method call to a more specialized method signature in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, introspection

I had a hard time with the title on this one. Example will explain best.

Given the following:

```java
interface Request {}

interface Response {}

interface Capability {
    Response perform(Request r)
}

interface FooCapability extends Capability {
   class FooCapabilityRequest implements Request;
   class FooCapabilityResponse implements Response;
}

class Performer implements FooCapability {
    public FooCapability.FooCapabilityResponse perform(FooCapability.FooCapabilityRequest r) { ... }
    public Response perform(Request r) {
      // detect the implementing class of r and
      // call the method with the more specialized 
      // signature above
    }
}

// The idea is to be able to do:
Performer p = new Performer();

// (...using the Request interface as type...)
Request request = new FooCapability.FooCapabilityRequest();

// this should call the generic perform(),
// then be forwarded to the more specialized implementation 
p.perform(request);
```

How would one go about this?

Comment: Okay @azurefrog, I updated it for you. A lot more verbose now. :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it's an antipattern and almost certainly more complicated than you need. Are you trying to be able to automatically dispatch based on the consumed request type?

Comment: @chrylis yeah. It's not really necessary with this setup since performer can just accept concrete implementations and does the right thing. It was mostly curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are (90% of) the answer here. Since `Class` is now generic, we can expose the expected request type in a way that guarantees we'll be able to invoke the interface with one of "those".

```
interface Capability<R, S> {
  S perform(R request);

  Class<R> requestType();
  // resultType too if you want
}
```

Then in your composite:

```
Map<Class<?>, Capability<?, ?>> capabilities = collectionOfCapabilities.stream()
    .collect(toMap(Capability::requestType, identity()));
```

The one downside is that because Java doesn't support "floating" generics here, that map itself will be type-unsafe. However, since we ourselves know that the first `?` and the second `?` match because of the way we constructed it, we can say

```
@SuppressWarnings("unsafe") // safe because we keyed the map based on the request type
private <R> Capability<R, ?> findCapability(Class<R> requestType) {
  return (Capability<R, ?>) capabilities.get(requestType);
}
```

Additionally associating the result type here if desired is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Nifty. Thanks for this.

Comment: Note that with this pattern the "Performer" can't inherit from multiple Capability<R,S> interfaces, so we can't use a type check to see if a performer has a capability.

Comment: Not quite, but in this case I strongly encourage you to examine the Spring `ConversionService` as a solid real-world example.